# query left join or data insert?

Tags: mysql, sql

OK - I have three tables, structured below

```
tbl_1
------
userid
teamid
teamname
eliminated

tbl_2
------
teamid
week
team

tbl_3
------
team
NFLname

nfl-schedule
------
week
time
awayteam (same as "team" in tbl_3)
hometeam (same as "team" in tbl_3)
```

This is a query on a "survivor league" where I  need to get the teamid, teamname, eliminated, team, week, and NFLname for each week. If a user hasn't selected a team for this week, week 2 for instance, I want to see a blank row for that week. I"m assuming I could backfill the rows into the database for each teamid, but was wondering if I could do this simply with sql and some inner joins?

```
select a.teamid, a.teamname, a.eliminated, b.team, b.week, c.NFLnamefrom `tbl_1` a
            left join `tbl_2` b on a.teamid = b.teamid
            left join `tbl_3` c on c.`team` = b.team
            where a.userid =  XXX
```

Comment: A SQL query can only return results from data in the tables it is processing.  If no data is in the tables, it won't appear.  So even your approach won't work if no user has selected a team for a particular week.

Comment: No way to "fake" a null row with some magic sql :)

Comment: . . If you have a table of available weeks, then edit your query and include it in the question.

Comment: ahhh - you're a smart guy :). I do have a table of weeks, let me edit the post quickly ( < 5 mins)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use left joins for this, but you have to take care of the order you use the tables.
Another problem would be when there is a pick for this week from another user, so I think you would have to use a subquery like this:

```
select w.week,t.teamid,t.teamname,t.eliminated,t.team,t.NFLname 
from nfl-schedule w
left join ( 
select a.teamid, a.teamname, a.eliminated, b.team, b.week, c.NFLname
from `tbl_1` a
left join `tbl_2` b on a.teamid = b.teamid
left join `tbl_3` c on c.`team` = b.team
where a.userid =  XXX
) t on w.week = t.week
```